# Asset file not being included on older versions of Android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a webview Android project. It's working fine enough on later Android Versions, but when I use API 25 or 26 (26 is Android 8 I believe), there's a certain file not being copied into the installed APK.

All the files for the HTML/JavaScript/CSS for my webview project are in the `assets` directory. The HTML is all inside of `assets/index.html` and the JavaScript files are all inside of `assets/js`, with some of the files being inside of a subfolder there, `assets/js/v35/`.

That latter folder has a specific file that isn't being brought into the APK, but only on older versions of Android. `assets/js/v35/picks-singles-35.js`.

The name of the file used to be longer, but I made it shorter thinking it might be a file name length problem, or path length problem. Making the file name shorter didn't help. I thought maybe the file's too big, but there are other .js files in that folder that are bigger that are getting copied in. I thought, maybe this file isn't being copied because the APK has reached its limit, so it's stopping any file after the last file it can load - so I changed the file name to being with 'a' so that it would be one of the first files to be included, rather than risk being excluded because it's later in the file-name list. That didn't help either.

So this file, picks-singles-35.js, isn't being included and it's apparently not because it's too big, the file name is too long, or because it's being excluded in favour of other files with earlier file names. I'm completely at a loss about why this file is being excluded on Android 8 devices, but not when it's an Android 11 device.

Comment: An APK itself is just a file. The APK itself does not vary by version of the OS on which you install the APK. You can verify for yourself whether this file is in the APK by examining the APK contents, such as via Analyze APK in Android Studio. So... what are your specific symptoms? For example, are you getting an error message from something, and if so, what is the message and what is raising it?

Comment: try to rename it to picks_singles_35.js

Comment: @CommonsWare the specific symptoms are, all features connected to this file do not work, and when I use Chrome debugger to inspect the running app, this file does not appear in the list of files, while all the other .js files do. The javascript is erroring in exactly the way it would if this file did not exist.

Comment: I have a new theory: this file is not showing up in Chrome debugger because this file uses a more modern feature of Javascript than the instance of Chrome supports. I have a class with `static` variables and methods on it - would that cause the file to disappear entirley from the chrome list of files? If it was trying to run in Chrome which doesn't support static?

Comment: Just try to open the file yourself using AssetsManager. Or list the content of the folder. Only then you could blame the ide not having included the file.

Comment: And did you try with underscores? Please react on such hints.

Comment: Dashes Vs underscores is not the problem, I can confirm. Other files are loading with dashes in the file name

Comment: I found the answer to my question. The file was included in the APK, but was not showing up in Chrome Debugger on older versions of android which had older versions of Chrome installed - because the file used Static Class variables. Chrome didn't show the files in the list for that reason - I guess it wasn't showing .js files which had syntax errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question because I misdiagnosed what was actually going on.